# run 12.04 and 13.10 with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

Is it possible to run two or more instances of Ubuntu on the same system, in addition to Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can only run one OS at a time, you reboot into it.

The only exception would be if you ran them in a Vritual Machine, such as Virtualbox.

**https://www.virtualbox.org/**

There are many other options for Virtualization, VMWare, KVM, LXC, OpenVZ ....

You can run multiple OS with virtualization, your only limitation then would be hard ddrive space and RAM.

Comment: Thanks very much - actually, my intent was to be able to run EITHER 13.10 or 12.04 or Windows 8, not simultaneously - there are a couple of programs that seem to run well on 12.04, but not on 13.10.  I wanted to choose between the OS, depending on what I wanted to run.

Comment: You would then "dual boot" or in your case, multiboot. the boot loader used in Ubuntu (grub) will allow you to boot as many OS as you have installed.